# Array has length on Chrome Console but not when .length is called

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I've encountered a somewhat weird behavior. I have an object array that returns a length of 0. However, if I log the array in the console the length method shows a length of 8.

Anyone knows what's going on? Also how can I get the length of on code? [Here's a link to an image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdC1E.png)

Here's my code:

```
   function createObjArrStreamers () {
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        connectToApi(i); 
    }
}

function passApiDataToStreamersArr (data, i) {
    if (data.stream !== null) {
         streamersObjArr.push({
               name: users[i],
               streaming_status: data.stream.stream_type,
               game: data.stream.game,
               twitchID: data.stream._id,
               linkToStream: data.stream.channel.url
         });
      } else {
      streamersObjArr.push({
          name: users[i],
          streaming_status: "Offline"
        });
    }
}


function connectToApi ( i ) {
var  targetUrl = url + users[i] + "?" + "callback=?";
  $.getJSON(targetUrl, function (userData){
      passApiDataToStreamersArr(userData, i);
  });
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking the length? What you see in console is a live object (not a snapshot) that may have been updated after your initial log

Comment: Can you please tell us where exactly in the code you are logging the length to the console? Because it seems that the logging is happening before the data is pushed to the array.

Comment: This happens when you have asynchronous calls to mutate the array yet check the array in the main timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ***asynchronous*** requests being made and no way to know when they have all completed.

You can create an array of promises and use `$.when` to resolve when the whole promise array has resolved ... meaning after all requests have successfully completed:

```
function createObjArrStreamers() {

  var promises = users.map(function(user, i) {
    // connectToApi function returns request promise, add it to array
    return connectToApi(i);
  });

  $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
    // full array should now be populated
    console.log('Arr length: ', streamersObjArr.length)
  });   

}

function passApiDataToStreamersArr(data, i) {
  //...... No changes
}


function connectToApi(i) {
  var targetUrl = url + users[i] + "?" + "callback=?";
  // return promise
  return $.getJSON(targetUrl, function(userData) {
    passApiDataToStreamersArr(userData, i);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because I can't see the vars you're logging, but I assume what you're doing is referencing the initial length of the array in a stored variable. See bellow for my assumption:

```
let arr = []
let b = arr.length
arr.push('d')
console.log(arr.length, b)
// arr.length will be 1 and b will be 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

The console shows updated info when you expand it.

Before expanding it it shows an empty array "[]".

So, when you do print console.log(array), it actually has length 0. However, later on, you add some data to it somehow, and therefore you can see all that data.

i.e:

```
var a = [];
console.log(a, a.length); // will print [], 0
a.push('a');
```

When you check console, you will see [], when you expand the object you will see it has element 0: 'a', and you will also see the 0 length